# ITextSharp - get image at a particular location

Tags: image, itext, extract

What I need to do is extract a 2D DataMatrix (bitmap) bar code and read it. I can make this work however, I have to loop through all the images on every page. This is taking a long time when I have 1000’s of pages, so I was wondering if it was possible to define a location(rectangle)of where the image(barcode) was  and just extract that image?

The bar code is always i the same location.
*note: I'm using Spire.Barcode from e-IceBlue*

Thank you for any help.

CODE RenderFilter  snippet:

```
public class MyRegionTextRenderFilter : RenderFilter {

            /** the region to allow text from */
            private RectangleJ filterRect;
            public PdfImageObject image;
            /**
             * Constructs a filter
             * @param filterRect the rectangle to filter text against.  Note that this is a java.awt.Rectangle !
             */
            public MyRegionTextRenderFilter(RectangleJ filterRect) {
                this.filterRect = filterRect;
            }

            /**
             * Constructs a filter
             * @param filterRect the rectangle to filter text against.
             */
            public MyRegionTextRenderFilter(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle filterRect)
            {
                this.filterRect = new RectangleJ(filterRect);
            }


            /** 
             * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderFilter#allowText(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo)
             */
            public override bool AllowImage(ImageRenderInfo  renderInfo)
            {
                var matrix = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();
                float left = matrix[6];
                float top = matrix[7];
                float width = matrix[0];
                float height = matrix[4];

                return filterRect.IntersectsLine(left, top, width, height);
            }
        }
```

Code calling :

```
  RectangleJ rect = new RectangleJ(518.0f, 18.0f, 23.0f, 23.0f);
            PdfReaderContentParser parser2 = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);
            RenderFilter[] renderFilter = new RenderFilter[1];
            renderFilter[0] = new MyRegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
            FilteredTextRenderListener listener2 = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderFilter);
            parser2.ProcessContent(3, listener2);
```

Comment: You may want to use a `RegionTextRenderFilter`.

Comment: Ok I know how to get text with RegionTextRenderFilter and I know how to get image info, but how does one get a image from a RegionTextRenderFilter ?

Comment: Ok, not the `RegionTextRenderFilter` as is but an equivalent for images. Simply copy the [RegionTextRenderFilter](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/RegionTextRenderFilter.cs) and add an `AllowImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)` implementation similar to the existing `AllowText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)` method.

Comment: Ok great why don't you place that as answer and I will accept ii. thanks again

Comment: A remark on the code after your edit: your `float top = matrix[7]` usually is a `bottom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser namespace of iText(Sharp) allows filtering of information digested by an [`IRenderListener`](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/IRenderListener.cs) implementation by using a [`RenderFilter`](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/RenderFilter.cs):

```
public abstract class RenderFilter {

    /**
     * @param renderInfo
     * @return true if the text render operation should be performed
     */
    public virtual bool AllowText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo){
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param renderInfo
     * @return true is the image render operation should be performed
     */
    public virtual bool AllowImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo){
        return true;
    }
}
```

For filtering by area there already is a textual render filter, the [`RegionTextRenderFilter`](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/RegionTextRenderFilter.cs).

For your task simply copy it and add an `AllowImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)` implementation similar to the existing `AllowText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)` method.

Comment: Hi MKL, I got pretty far but I got a little loss, was wondering if you could take a look at the code(above) I can find the image base on the rectangle but I can't figure out how to get the image? any help would be great. thanks again

Comment: Your original code contined a `MyImageRenderListener` - why don't you continue using it or at least a comparable image listener?

Comment: yes, that what i did late yesterday worked great thanks!